# Reference ExPex example's page number without \label

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, expex

*Question:*
Is there some way to accomplish a `\getpageref` equivalent of `\getref` and `\getfullpageref` equivalent of `\getfullref` in `expex`?

*Background:*
I have a lengthy document which uses `expex` for hundreds of examples.  Currently, I am using the `expex` notation for all examples where the label immediately follows `\ex` or `\pex` inside angle brackets i.e. `<>`.  None of these examples uses `\label`, and so I reference examples using `\getfullref`.

For a sizeable number of examples, I repeat the example several chapters later and want to reference back to the original using this notation: [(EXNUM), repeated from p. PNUM]

Referencing the example number is not an issue.  However, I realized that `\pageref` cannot recognize ExPex's tags.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\ex<expex item>
    \gla test //
    \glft test //
\xe

\getfullref{expex item}

\pageref{expex item}
\end{document}
```

Will produce `1` and `??`, as in the image:

[image: comparison of ExPex example with \getfullref and \pageref]

You can solve this by changing `\ex<expex item>` to `\ex<expex item>\label{expex item}`.  Such as:

```
\ex<expex item>\label{expex item}
   \gla test //
   \glft test //
\xe
```

However, there are some reasons why I would prefer hooking into ExPex's system instead, if possible.

- I have many of these cross-referenced examples.  It is not an arbitrary task of adding `\label{...}` in only a few cases, as you might in a smaller document
- In principle, it seems like there should be way to also its page number, just like the `\label`+`\ref`+`\pageref` system allows for.

The [ExPex](https://ctan.org/pkg/expex?lang=en) package [documentation on pp. 60-66](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/expex/expex-doc.pdf) discusses references.  However, I can only find hard-coded page numbers in the documentation.  So, you lose some benefit of the built-in `expex` system if you only use `\label` (discussed on p. 66 under `Support for the LaTex \label and \ref commands`) or have redundancy issues.  It's also problematic to retro-fit large documents which didn't originally use the `\label` approach.  You also need multiple labels in `\pex`, if you only want to refer to part B, C, D, etc. (which becomes relevant when page breaks occur).

In case it is relevant, my actual document uses `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages.  I did not include these in the example, because they behavior is identical for me.  However, if one of these packages can hook in to the page number, that would also work.

**-- Edit --**

My example was slightly unclear because I only provided `\ex`, but not `\pex`.  I hope that any approach can also apply to part A, B, C, etc. in a multipart `\pex`.  Here is an example (with the current patch provided in @ulrike-fischer's answer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\deftag{\label{#2}}{}{\fail}

\begin{document}
    \ex<ex item>
        \gla test //
        \glft test //
    \xe

    Reference:
    \getfullref{ex item} on p. \pageref{ex item}

    \pex<pex item>
        \a<A> test2 //
        \a<B> test3 //
    \xe

    General reference:
    \getfullref{pex item} on p. \pageref{pex item}

    A reference:
    \getfullref{pex item.A} on p. \pageref{pex item.A}

    B reference:
    \getfullref{pex item.B} on p. \pageref{pex item.B}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Unresolved references to part A and B in \pex]

The original question still applies, but I wanted to clarify that I hope an answer can also hook into these parts and not only the example number.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\deftag{\label{#2}}{}{\fail}

\begin{document}

\ex<expex item>
\begingl
    \gla test //
    \glft blub //
\endgl
\xe

\getfullref{expex item}

\pageref{expex item}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about patching.  This only works for `\ex`, however.  I realize I should have explicitly included a `\pex` in the example also - I will update it.  Is there a similar patch that can do the same in multipart `\pex` examples?  For example, `\a<B>` and referring to it via `\pageref{expex item.B}`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it works for `\ex` and `\pex`, but does not work for part A, B, C, etc. within `\pex`.  I have updated the question and provided an image with both.  You can see `\pageref` still cannot hook into those parts.  Could you also provide a brief explanation in your answer how it copies the ExPex label into `\label` via `\deftag`?  It might be useful for someone else in the future.

Comment: Don't edit your question so that it makes my answer invalid. That is rather unfair. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: Your answer did manage to work for the provided code, however it did not completely answer the question.  It works for `\getref` but not `\getfullref`.  The problem was that my example was incomplete for my question.  I also mentioned this in my paragraph about the ExPex documentation.  I apologize for the original omission in the code.

Comment: Could you please add the following to your answer?  Patching `\ep@putlabel@b` command by replacing `\deftaglabel{\@optionaltag}` with `\label{\@localextag.\@optionaltag}\deftaglabel{\@optionaltag}`.  Using both patches, `\getfullref` works in all situations.